# Duvida HTML soma de atributos

Tags: javascript, html

Bom dia, estou com a seguinte duvida, estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação e preciso saber como poderia somar um atributo de texto ( como formulario ) a um link.

Obs: sem necessidade de usar document.getelementbyid.

Exemplo: http://teste.bla.bla/  +  o texto digitado em um text area.

Vou colar meu code

```
<form 
  action="http://teste.com.br/ 
  method="POST" 
  onSubmit="this.BTEnvia.value='Enviando...'; 
  this.BTEnvia.disabled=true;">
```

ai dentro deste link queria colar um texto digitado pelo usuario

exemplo usuario digitou "exemplo"
ai na hora que desse submite somar este link do form action + o texto que ele digitou no caso "exemplo"

Na forma de conseguir abrir este link com form action.

Alguém está disposto a me ajudar ?

Comment: Olá, podes explicar melhor a pergunta?

Comment: Por que tem que ser um textarea e não um input text, que seria o mais indicado?

Comment: Porque não pode usar `document.getElementById` ?

Answer (score 0):

Olá @sev3ndie,

vc pode realizar o submit com ajax,

js:

```
$("#form1").submit(function(){

    $.ajax({
      url:"get_link.php",
      success:function(data){
           window.open("http://site.com.br/"+data);
          }
    });

    return false

});//end submit
```

get_link.php:

```
<?php

   $get_link = $_POST['get_link'];
   echo $get_link;

?>
```

Comment: Vish cara tem outra alternativa ? ajax não manjo.

Comment: Confere a do @Lucas Carvalho, parece que está dentro da idéia

Answer (score 0):

Não entendi muito bem, mas, seria isso?

```js
function myNewUrl(url, action, val){
    return url +'?' + action + '=' + val;
}

document.querySelector('.my_form').addEventListener('submit', function(a){
   a.preventDefault();
   let valor = document.querySelector('.my_input').value;
   console.log(myNewUrl('http://minhaurl.com/', 'minhaAction', valor));
});
```

```html
<form class="my_form" method="POST">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Digite o action" class="my_input"/>
  <button>Enviar</button>  
</form>
```

Só trocar o console.log pela função de redirecionamento. Se não for isso, peço que explique melhor sua pergunta pois está muito difícil de responder.